# Hide view button in my account – orders – actions column

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce and I'm trying to hide the "view" button in my account – orders – actions column.
https://snipboard.io/oKzydI.jpg
The below CSS code was suggested but hasn't worked.

`.woocommerce table.my_account_orders .button:first-child { display: none;}`

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong and what I can do to hide the "view" button?

Comment: to answer need to check the HTML structure and it must match your website, otherwise, it will not work.
Are you able to upload inspect snapshot for the same button?

Comment: Ok, Please see link:https://snipboard.io/RvMJxk.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it

```
.woocommerce-button.button.view{display:none;}
```

Comment: It works! I put it in the extra css under customise. For some reason i had to put the code in twice, however it now works. Thanks @OnkarSingh